# exec() on a java program in php-cgi on a raspberry pi

Tags: java, php, cgi, exec, raspberry-pi

So, I have a php application, running through cgi, with nginx.
I have a .jar program used to print barcodes on, guess what, a barcode printer (Zebra)!.

My php application runs the .jar program using the exec() command. On my computer (php, cgi, nginx, debian testing), it works.

Now, I'm trying the same thing, but on a raspberry pi. Debian (wheezy, raspberry version), php, cgi, nginx.
The exec() command does not fail (in the way I dont get a huge fatal error), does not return anything, and does not succeed neither.

The java command works fine when I try it in the shell, using the www-data user (the one running nginx/php-cgi). It works when I put it in a php-cli (cli, not cgi) script, and run it with the php command in the shell, with the www-data user :

```
<?php exec('java -cp /path/ Methode options');?>
$ php print.php
```

Cups configuration seems ok (I (the pi user) can print, the www-data user can print through command line (shell), root can print, everyone can).

I'm confused and can't find where the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried adding the extra `&$output` argument to exec. And `var_dump` the contents after executing the java command

Comment: yes, I tried, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `2>&1` at the end of your exec(), in example: `exec('java -cp /path/ Method options 2>&1');`

Edit:
I would not advice you to do this if it was a real server; but since its a PI you can edit the sudoers file and add the following

run `sudo visudo`

and add:

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

now modify your exec string with:
`exec('sudo java -cp /path/ Method options');`

Comment: Well, i tried your edit, but no more luck. I don't get it. It's as if the exec() function was just like 'function exec() { return;}'

Comment: Do you echo the exec();? Did you test with and without the ` 2>&1`?

Comment: Ok I tried again with sudo, and it worked (previous test was after a downgrade of the java version).

The thing is, www-data is in the lpadmin group. Shouldn't it be okay then ?